# How can I use webcam as a source of Media with LibVLCSharp

Tags: webcam, libvlcsharp

I want to stream my webcam. How can I do that?

using var libVLC = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true);

using var media = new Media(libVLC, new Uri("HD Webcam"));

using var mp = new MediaPlayer(media);

mp.Play();

Also want to use libVLCharp as audio/video devices as receivers and sources.

Comment: How to  bridge between SIPSorcery and libVLCSharp to allow the use of audio / video devices as receivers and sources.

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments, they will be missed. Only post one question per post.

Comment: We wanted to implement SIPSorcercy with LibVLCSharp, and some relative progress may be found in the examples, but there are still some complexities with libvlc that must be worked around before you can have a product that uses this. Long story short : too hard for a sample, you'd better use ffmpeg for that use case

Answer (score 2):

Use `dshow://` as the media URL, if you're using windows.

As a rule of thumb, try to find the syntax for the VLC command line, and this will give you the way for LibVLCSharp.